# Prevent git commit if Typescript error is detected

Tags: git, typescript, azure-devops

I am programming in Typscript in Visual Code and I noticed I was able to git (azure) commit and push to the server even though there was an error in my code which resulted in a failed build. Of course I should always make sure that my code builds but as a security measure is it possible to automatically prevent commit or push if there is a Typescript error in the code?

Comment: pre-commit hooks

Comment: You can use `pre-commit` or `pre-push` git hook and configure it to run `tsc` command (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add to pre-commit / pre-push hook with linter in package.json